# Is your Hall of Fallen Heroes public?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is your Hall of Fallen Heroes public at all? Is it possible to look at other people's heroes and admire them? Or is it entirely for your own records and memories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your Hall of Fallen Heroes shows up as a tab on your profile when viewed by other people.  It will also most likely be included in the soon-to-be-released Armory.